# How to query duplicates results MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

While every question I found is talking about removing duplicates I need these duplicates.

Let's say my database is

```
+-------+-----------+
| ID    | letter    |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | A         |
| 2     | B         |
| 4     | Z         |
+-------+-----------+
```

I need to query a person name so let say the name is "ABA" when I query like this

```
select * from letters where letter = 'A' or letter = 'B' or letter = 'A'
```

My result will be

```
+-------+-----------+
| ID    | letter    |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | A         |
| 2     | B         |
+-------+-----------+
```

I want the output will include the 3rd letter as a separate row.

```
+-------+-----------+
| ID    | letter    |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | A         |
| 2     | B         |
| 3     | A         |
+-------+-----------+
```

Maybe I don't know the right term but I didn't find even one answer that give me half a solution.

there is one entry but can I can the entry again? if I query for "nina" get the full name and not just "nia"

Comment: *My result will be* No. You will receive 3 rows, not 2.

Comment: @Akina - I added an update to the question with screenshot

Comment: Akina is right, though. If you only get one result row for a letter, this means there is only one entry for the letter in the table.

Comment: Thank you, ahh I'm so stupid. on the original table there is one entry but can I can the entry again? if I query for "nina" get the full name and not just "nia"

Comment: Does the order of the result matter? Must it be `n i n a` or can it be `a i n n`?

Comment: post your actual table and what result you expact , your question is not properly cleared

Comment: @ThorstenKettner order matter.

Comment: Okay, I've written an answer. You should edit your request still and add the information about the required order. And your result has a typo: The ID of the letter A is 1, not 3.

Answer (score 2):

### Original answer (and recommended approach)

Use a recursive query to convert the name into rows with one letter each. Then join with your letters table.

```
with recursive word_letters (word, pos, letter) as
(
  select @name, 1, substr(@name, 1, 1)
  union all
  select word, pos + 1, substr(word, pos + 1, 1)
  from word_letters
  where pos < length(word)
)
select letters.*
from word_letters
join letters on letters.letter = word_letters.letter
order by word_letters.pos;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6547c21d2dd9223270615047d46d9783

### UPDATE: Workaround for old MySQL versions

Build a table of positions (numbers) large enough to cover the longest word. Then join the word in order to get the position for each letter in it. Then join your other table.

```
select letters.*
from 
(
  select hundreds.digit * 100 + tens.digit * 10 + units.digit + 1 as pos
  from       (select 0 as digit union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) units
  cross join (select 0 as digit union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) tens
  cross join (select 0 as digit union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) hundreds
) positions
join (select @name as word) w on length(w.word) >= positions.pos
join letters on letters.letter = substr(w.word, positions.pos, 1)
order by positions.pos;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=db3762d5705ce5eb77e628c4d4058485

Comment: First I must say thank you and great solution, do you have something that will work with MySQL 5.7?

Comment: Must you work with such an old MySQL version? I've added an alternative for that to my answer.

Comment: I need to check with our hosting to answer the version issue. Thank you for you time again, I checked again and I think your solution for 5.7 has issues too: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dd21d70445e5ec4852b00457e82983a7

Comment: Ah, okay, MySQL 5.7 doesn't support table/column alias combinations like `tens(digit)`, so we must move the column alias inside the subquery. I've done that and updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using any of the below queries. For your reference visit the link below to test the output.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5e9f3/1

The table created and the populated data is as below

```
create table tbl(ID int,letter varchar(2));
insert into tbl(ID,letter) values(1,'A');
insert into tbl(ID,letter) values(2,'B');
insert into tbl(ID,letter) values(3,'A');
insert into tbl(ID,letter) values(4,'Z');
insert into tbl(ID,letter) values(5,'C');
```

and now the query

```
select * from tbl where letter in ('A','B');
```

or

```
select * from tbl where letter ='A' or letter='B';
```